# How to run multiple jobs using abaqus python script?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to run multiple jobs using abaqus python where different models are run for each of the umat subroutine available  but the  loop exits after the first job is executed

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
current_Path = os.getcwd()

umat_Path = current_Path+'\\'+'UMATS'
umat_list = os.listdir(umat_Path)
print(umat_list)

model_Path = current_Path+'\\'+'Models'
model_list = os.listdir(model_Path)

print(model_list)

os.chdir(model_Path)
for umat in umat_list:
    umat = umat_Path+'\\'+umat
    for model in model_list:
        model=os.path.splitext(model)[0]
        odbname=umat+model
        os.system('cmd /k "abaqus job=%s user=%s globalmodel=%s interactive"'%(model,umat,odbname))
```

Comment: You can use `waitForCompletion()` command in order stop further execution of the script until currently runnig job completes or aborts. You can use this command after `os.system...'  command.

Comment: Hello Satish my objective of the code is that,there are different umats stored in UMAT folder and different models stored in Models folder.Now for each of the umat present in UMAT folder, i have to run it against each of the models in Models folder and get the output odb file. for example umat1.for and umat2.for are present in UMAT folder and model1.inp and model2.inp are present in model folder. Now the problem is that the compiler exits after executing model1 with umat1.for.The for loop is not working. I am using the abaqus python to  run the above script.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system` as the former gives you more flexibility on input and output options.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to use `waitForCompletion()` method. 
And I think, you cannot use 'cmd' command to submit the job. Instead, create job from input file using `JobFromInputFile()` as you have input file. Then submit the job using `submit()` method. and at the end you can use `waitForCompletion()` to wait for the submitted job to either complete or abort.  
Find the snippet of code:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import job  # to access job related commands

current_Path = os.getcwd()

umat_Path = current_Path+'\\'+'UMATS'
umat_list = os.listdir(umat_Path)

model_Path = current_Path+'\\'+'Models'
model_list = os.listdir(model_Path)

os.chdir(model_Path)
for umat in umat_list:
    umat = umat_Path+'\\'+umat
    for model in model_list:
        model=os.path.splitext(model)[0]
        odbname=umat+model
        myJob = mdb.JobFromInputFile(name=model, 
                inputFileName=odbname, type=ANALYSIS, 
                atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90, 
                memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True, 
                explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, userSubroutine=umat, 
                scratch='', parallelizationMethodExplicit=DOMAIN, numDomains=1, 
                activateLoadBalancing=False, multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, numCpus=1)
        
        myJob.submit()
        myJob.waitForCompletion()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and i would also try the way you explained.Using cmd worked for me and the problem resolved by changing cmd /k to cmd /c in the last line of code